# How can my ListBox ItemSource implement an observable collection in WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` (EmpView) which is populated by a select statement via LINQ to SQL from a typed dataset.
I have to put a button to be able to refresh the list box with updated data.

How do I make my dataset (if possible) or get my `ListBox` `ItemSource` to implement an observable collection?

Here is my code

```
public partial class ListOfEmployees : UserControl
{
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

    var employees = from emp in db.EmployeeMasters
    orderby emp.Surname
    select emp;         

    EmpView.ItemsSource = employees;
}
```

Comment: Related: [Bind LINQ expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029458/bind-linq-expression)

Comment: @H.B., i still do not understand after checking the link you posted.
How do i sore the result of my query in an observable collection before binding to the listbox?

Comment: @H.B., thanks for the timely response, but i still do not get it.
How do i store the results of my select query inn an observable colllection before binding to the EmpView listbox?

Comment: If you put the items into an observable collection then that collection will create change notifications if it is changed, but is that really what you want? The collection cannot know if the query you used to initially create its contents would after some time create a different output. That is why i think you would want something like a bindable LINQ.

Comment: @H.B. ..If you put the items into an observable collection then that collection will create change notifications if it is changed, but is that really what you want? 
=>Yes this exactly what i want.
i want change notifications on my UI as i perform CRUD operations on the collection/itemsource.

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do then is create a new [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) with the selected items added via the constrctor or [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404.aspx). e.g.

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(employees);
EmpView.ItemsSource = observableCollection;
```

The type of your item class may of course be different. To easily change the collection you might want to store a reference to it somewhere.

As noted in the comments this will only take note of changes caused by explicit operations on the collection.

Comment: thanks for the post.
I have tried it out but still cannot get it to work.
When i add data, the UI still does not get updated.
Do i need to implement the INotifypropertyChanged interface in my usercontrol outrightly?

Comment: You should not need to implement that in UserControls as you would normally use [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) which provide change notifications, if that `ItemsSource` is not a DP you should change that.

Comment: @froodo You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for you Employee class and then it should work..!!

Comment: @Vijay thanks for the comment...but my employee class is an automatically generated LINQ to SQL class.
Is there anyway i can work around this?

Comment: @froodo Derive a custom Employee class from the auto generated Employee class and in your custom derived class, implement the INotifyProperyChanged; then use this custom class in your LINQ query and observable collection variable. FYI, This is in addition to the answer posted by H.B. and I suppose then it should work..

Comment: @froodo: You only need change notifications on the Employees if their properties change and they are shown somwhere in the view, they are not relevant to the collection changes